# how to determine what is the QNetworkRequest Method (get or post)?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qnetworkrequest

When i use QWebView to browse websites and monitor requests using `QWevView.Page().networkAccessManager().finished` signal, how can I detemine what is taht request method (Post or Get)?

this is my code:

```
def __init__()
    self.web=QWebView()
    self.web.setUrl(myUrl)
    self.web.page().networkAccessManager().finished.connect(self.checkMethod)
    self.web.show()

def checkMethod(self,reply):
    req=reply.request()
    print(req.Method())# what can I do for this?
```

Comment: Why not just read the documentation for [QNetworkReply](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html)?

Comment: I read that but I didn't find any thing about this. what function does this?

Comment: You didn't find `operation()`?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't know what's the meaning of operation. thanks a lot @ekhumoro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can user`operation()` method for this 
it return `QNetworkAccessManager::Operation` which include `{ HeadOperation, GetOperation, PutOperation, PostOperation, DeleteOperation, CustomOperation }`